# How to Fix Rounded Borders on Text that is Wrapped

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I have a table in my application (generated dynamically) that has 3 columns. The cells where the text is a too long, it wraps around which is fine except the rounded borders now look bad.

[image]

Currently, my table is wrapped in a `DIV` with an id set as **item-list** and the CSS is as follows:

```
#item-list {
   text-align: center;
}


#item-list table {
margin: auto auto; 
}

#item-list td {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

#item-list a {
font-size: 0.8em;
color: #FFF;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
padding: 4px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #1a546a;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

#item-list a:hover {
background-color: #8f2525;
}
```

My question is, is there a way using CSS to make the wrapped text still be rounded on all edges?

**[Disclaimer]** My expertise is in PHP. CSS is a skill where I know enough to usually accomplish what I need to do, but not much beyond amateurish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to your `#item-list a`.

```
#item-list a {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #1a546a;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I've set up a quick example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/g5YcT/

**Display Block**

> The element is displayed as a block element (like paragraphs and
>   headers). A block element has some whitespace above and below it and
>   does not tolerate any HTML elements next to it

Comment: Yeah I had to wait. There is a mandatory waiting period before you can accept an answer. Thanks again.